# Where can I ask questions about Joomla! CMS?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Sometimes I want to ask questions about Joomla! CMS. I see a [wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site on the network. Where can I ask my questions about Joomla! CMS?

Comment: What kind of question about Joomla?

Comment: What **kind** of question? Programming? Deploying? Something else?

Comment: Programming, like editing modules and components

Comment: Programming questions can be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What **kind** of programming?

Comment: Stackoverflow, tagged joomla. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/joomla

Comment: as kind as wordpress questions

Comment: If its simple programming then you can simply ask it at the main site, if it was just suggestion based then you should ask it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for edit [Mat](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158667/mat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if its about programming; coding. It can be asked at stackoverflow.

If its about the basics of how codes work then you can ask it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com that's the site where you can ask about suggestion. Suggestions would be more welcomed there!

If you want to ask help regarding the simple code, I have suggested to use the Stackoverflow.com and just add a tag of `Joomla!`

Here is a stream of the questions tagged under `Joomla!`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/joomla?sort=newest&pageSize=15

And once again, the site that you provided is a site specially for wordpress. Which means either it was a proposal at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and now its a site.

You can also suggest a proposal there! So that other developers that need a site for `Joomla!` might say thanks when they go to [Joomla on stackexchange(If ever created!)](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Good luck :) Cheers!

Comment: You're always most welcome! :)

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla <- better link for a possible future Joomla site